# Get dynamic text with python and present it in LaTeX, format depending on content

Tags: python, latex, presentation

I try to gather some graphics and text from different folders and present them in a comprehensive way. For this I use python to copy them into one folder and derive a dynamic LaTeX presentation, where I plot the copied graphics and print the text. The problem I'm facing now is, that I can derive the title for a slide dynamically from a text file, but if it's too long it will obviously wrap around. This dynamic title can be pretty long, so it might fill the whole slide. What I'd like to do now is to limit the space used by this text, without losing its information. The non-elegant solution I have to this problem is to count the characters and if it's over a certain threshold, use a smaller font. This solution is tedious and not optimal, I'd love to hear a better idea.

Comment: Is Python handling the formatting or is LaTeX?

Comment: Right now it's LaTeX, as I see a better chance to handle this problem there. But this can be changed.

Comment: You could put the title in a [minipage](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/anton/latex/ltx-267.html).

Comment: That's a good starting point, I checked out the minipage, thanks for the tip. Problem now is, that the text which is too big simply doesn't  get printed. I'm rather looking for a solution where the text gets "squeezed" into the box.